# adding values, when changing clicked radio button android

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

My problem is that when I checked answer from radiobutton and want to change checked answer to other radiobutton, total value of points increase (he calculate both values of answers). I have 7 RadioGroup, with 3 RadioButton each. Is it possible to block this calculation? I want to have a possibility to change my checked radiobutton to another, without increasing total value.

Here's my code:

```
public class question1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Necessary to calculate points
    List<Integer> points;
    int score = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1);

        points = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //Passing editText value to this activity
        final TextView textView = ( TextView ) findViewById(R.id.pName);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        textView.setText(str);

        //Sending editText value to next activity
        final Button start = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.so);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for (int index = 0; index < points.size(); index++) {
                    score = score + points.get(index);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(question1.this, fini.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", textView.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("totalPoints", score);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // Calculate totalPoints based on checked answers

    public List<Integer> onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = (( RadioButton ) view).isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.answerA1:
                //   if (checked) {
                // points = points + 3;
                points.set(0, 3);
                //  }
                break;
            case R.id.answerB1:
                //  if (checked) {
                //points = points + 2;
                points.set(0, 2);
                //  }
                break;
            case R.id.answerC1:
                //  if (checked) {
                //points = points + 1;
                points.set(0, 1);
                // }
                break;
            case R.id.answerA2:
                //  if (checked) {
                //points = points + 3;
                points.set(1, 3);
                //  }
                break;
            case R.id.answerB2:
                // if (checked) {
                //points = points + 2;
                points.set(1, 2);
                // }
                break;
            case R.id.answerC2:
                // if (checked) {
                //points = points + 1;
                points.set(1, 1);
                //}
                break;
            case R.id.answerA3:
                // if (checked) {
                //points = points + 3;
                points.set(2, 3);
                //}
                break;
            case R.id.answerB3:
                //if (checked) {
                //points = points + 2;
                points.set(2, 2);
                // }
                break;
            case R.id.answerC3:
                //  if (checked) {
                //points = points + 1;
                points.set(2, 1);
                //}
                break;

            case R.id.answerA4:
                //if (checked) {
                //points = points + 3;
                points.set(3, 3);
                //}
                break;
            case R.id.answerB4:
                //if (checked) {
                //points = points + 2;
                points.set(3, 2);
                //}
                break;
            case R.id.answerC4:
                //if (checked) {
                //points = points + 1;
                points.set(3, 1);
                //}
                break;
            case R.id.answerA5:
                //if (checked) {
                //points = points + 3;
                points.set(4, 3);
                //}
                break;
            case R.id.answerB5:
                //if (checked) {
                //points = points + 2;
                points.set(5, 2);
                //}
                break;
            case R.id.answerC5:
                //if (checked) {
                //points = points + 1;
                points.set(4, 1);
                //}
                break;

            case R.id.answerA6:
                //if (checked) {
                //points = points + 3;
                points.set(5, 3);
                //}
                break;
            case R.id.answerB6:
                //if (checked) {
                //points = points + 2;
                points.set(5, 2);
                //}
                break;
            case R.id.answerC6:
                //if (checked) {
                //points = points + 1;
                points.set(5, 1);
                //}
                break;
            case R.id.answerA7:
                //if (checked) {
                //points = points + 3;
                points.set(6, 3);
                //}
                break;
            case R.id.answerB7:
                //if (checked) {
                //points = points + 2;
                points.set(6, 2);
                //}
                break;
            case R.id.answerC7:
                //if (checked) {
                //points = points + 1;
                points.set(6, 1);
                //}
                break;
        }
        return points;
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.quizapp.question1">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/question1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="@string/a1"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerB1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/b1"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerC1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/c1"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FFCDDC39" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/question2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA2"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/a2"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerB2"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/b2"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerC2"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/c2"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#FFCDDC39" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/question3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA3"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/a3"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerB3"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/b3"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerC3"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/c3"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#FFCDDC39" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/question4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA4"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/a4"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerB4"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/b4"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerC4"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/c4"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#FFCDDC39" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/question5"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA5"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/a5"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerB5"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/b5"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerC5"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/c5"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#FFCDDC39" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/question6"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA6"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/a6"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerB6"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/b6"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerC6"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/c6"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#FFCDDC39" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/question7"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerA7"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/a7"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerB7"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/b7"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerC7"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/c7"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#FFCDDC39" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/so"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/Finish"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pName"
        android:text="0"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you tried subtracting the value in case radio button is not checked? so you would have an else statement that subtracts same value when a radio button is unchecked

Comment: @elmorabea yes I tried, and nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my answer as per your problem, try this i have test it as well.

```
public class question1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Necessary to calculate points
    List<Integer> points;
    int score = 0;
    int numberofquestions = 7;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1);

        points = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int index = 0; index < numberofquestions; index++) {
            points.add(index, 0);
        }

        //Passing editText value to this activity
        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pName);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        textView.setText(str);

        //Sending editText value to next activity
        final Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.so);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for (int index = 0; index < points.size(); index++) {
                    score = score + points.get(index);


                }
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), score + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   Intent intent = new Intent(question1.this, fini.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", textView.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("totalPoints", score);
                    score=0;
                    startActivity(intent);
                //score = 0;
            }
        });
    }
    // Calculate totalPoints based on checked answers

    public List<Integer> onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.answerA1:

                points.set(0, 3);
                break;
            case R.id.answerB1:

                points.set(0, 2);


                break;
            case R.id.answerC1:

                points.set(0, 1);


                break;

            case R.id.answerA2:

                points.set(1, 3);


                break;
            case R.id.answerB2:

                points.set(1, 2);


                break;
            case R.id.answerC2:

                points.set(1, 1);


                break;

            case R.id.answerA3:

                points.set(2, 3);


                break;
            case R.id.answerB3:

                points.set(2, 2);


                break;
            case R.id.answerC3:

                points.set(2, 1);


                break;

            case R.id.answerA4:

                points.set(3, 3);


                break;
            case R.id.answerB4:

                points.set(3, 2);


                break;
            case R.id.answerC4:

                points.set(3, 1);


                break;

            case R.id.answerA5:

                points.set(4, 3);


                break;
            case R.id.answerB5:

                points.set(4, 2);


                break;
            case R.id.answerC5:

                points.set(4, 1);


                break;

            case R.id.answerA6:

                points.set(5, 3);


                break;
            case R.id.answerB6:

                points.set(5, 2);


                break;
            case R.id.answerC6:

                points.set(5, 1);


                break;

            case R.id.answerA7:

                points.set(6, 3);


                break;
            case R.id.answerB7:

                points.set(6, 2);


                break;
            case R.id.answerC7:

                points.set(6, 1);
                break;
        }
        return points;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I create this method? In my onRadioButtonClicked, or should I replace them?

Comment: In EvaluateScore method define scenarios, those scenarios which you have defined in switch. Call this method on click i.e in your switch.

Comment: Create this method on your activity.

Comment: Have you understood this idea ?

Comment: Tell me one things ?
Are you showing this score at the end of quiz or after every question ?

Comment: i'm showing scores in next activity after clicked submit button

Comment: By seeing your code, i am assuming that you want to show score just after selection of radiobutton ? is it what you want ?

Comment: yes, I want to show total scores, because all my questions are in scroll view, so I want to show total scores after selecting all answers

Comment: what issue you are facing  now ?

Comment: it's said that i can't return points because required is int, and founded is java.util.List. so then I'm clicking to return this method in java.util.List. And that's probably why i can't open questions (java restart on phone)

Comment: //int points = 0; have you commit this line ? Share your full code with XML.

Comment: Congrats, enjoy.